# How can I get XmlSerializer deserialize attributes from multiple namespaces?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have a schema from a third party that I've generated c# objects from using Xsd2Code  (other options like xsd.exe, xmlspy etc either crashed or spewed 40mb of code that required their library to work)

Anyway, here's an example of a problem element from the schema:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:ns1="something" xmlns:ns2="somethinelse" targetNamespace="something">

  <xsd:complexType name="someType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element ref="element1" />
      <xsd:element ref="ns2:element2" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

 </xsd:schema>
```

The generated wrapper class looks like this:

```
[XmlType(Namespace="something")]
[XmlRoot("someType", Namespace="something", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class SomeType {
  public string Element1 { get; set; }

  [XmlElement(Namespace="somethinelse")]
  public string Element2 { get; set; }
}
```

Example xml using said schema:

```
<someType>
  <element1>SomeValue</element1>
  <ns2:element2>SomeValue2</element2>
</someType>
```

(Any errors are my typing the example. the schema is valid and un-changeable)

And now for the problem. when I try to deserialize the xml like so:

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeType));
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString))
SomeType obj = (SomeType)ser.Deserialize(reader)
```

The generated objects serialize correctly, adding the "ns2" to elements that need it. However, when deserializing, element1 gets set and element2 is left null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample data we were provided with had a typeo in the namespace which was causing it to deserialize wrong. Go figure.